# Wordpress: How to redirect to a blank page so inline/browser PDF creation will work?

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf, redirect, mpdf

I'm working with mPDF inside Wordpress.

I create a wordpress template and I have this code in it:

```
echo '<form name="MyForm" method="post">';
echo '<input name="download" type="submit" value="Download PDF" />';
echo '</form>';   

if(isset($_POST['download'])) {  
    include('mpdf/mpdf.php');
    $mpdf=new mPDF();
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($my_html_stuff);
    $mpdf->Output('my_file.pdf', 'D');
}
```

This doesn't work because Wordpress outputs stuff BEFORE `$mpdf->Output()`. I need something BLANK before `$mpdf->Output()` for this to work.

I'm thinking of first redirecting to a completely blank page and then doing the `$mpdf->Output()`. Any suggestions on how to best approach this?

Comment: Create another template without `get_header()` and `get_footer()` and put the mPDF code. It should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is you're outputting your form before you attempt to output the PDF.

Try outputting the PDF first and then killing the script:

```
if(isset($_POST['download'])) {  
    include('mpdf/mpdf.php');
    $mpdf=new mPDF();
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($my_html_stuff);
    $mpdf->Output('my_file.pdf', 'D');
    exit;
} 

echo '<form name="MyForm" method="post">';
echo '<input name="download" type="submit" value="Download PDF" />';
echo '</form>';
```

Also, make sure you do not have any output before your form processor. If this is a template in your theme do not call get_header. Best practice would be to take your form processor out of the template file. You could put it in your theme's functions.php file or implement it as a plugin. Keeping your backend processing separate from your frontend helps avoid situations like this.

Comment: I have the get_header() and get_footer() in the template (so it looks pretty), which gives me the problem. So should I just create another template without headers/footers with the mpdf stuff in it, then just an <a> link from my "pretty" template page to the blank page?

Comment: As I mentioned you may want to separate the form processing from the template. Add your form processing code to the functions.php file and then you can keep get_header and get_footer in your template without causing any issues.

Comment: If for some reason you must keep the form processing in the template file, move it above `get_header()` and it should work.